# WebDav for Hadoop 2.7.1

Tags: windows, macos, hadoop, hadoop2, webdav

I am using Hadoop 2.7.1 and I am trying to get WebDav services from it.

I am not finding enough resources for the solution.

I am finding an open issue:

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-225
```

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Help with what exactly? What is your task in hand? Documentation is available at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

Comment: is webhdfs the same as webdav?

Comment: No, webhdfs is a REST API. To my knowledge hadoop does not provide WebDAV service out of the box. There was some work-in-progress announced but it doesn't seem to make it to core distrib.